# Prevent validation of a specific required input field when button is clicked

Tags: visualforce, validation, actionregion

How can a `commandButton` ignore validation for one particular required field?

I am working on a seemingly simple portal account page with the following markup:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="MyController">
    <apex:form>

        <apex:pageBlock>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Update"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details" columns="2" id="details">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.LastName}" label="Contact Name" required="true"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!updateContact}" value="Update Contact" rerender="details"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Account.Name}" label="Account Name" required="true"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!updateAccount}" value="Update Account" rerender="details"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

When "Update Contact" is clicked I want the server to only validate the first field. Conversely the "Update Account" button should only validate the second field. When the main "Update" button is clicked I want the entire page to be validated.

I am seeing 2 solutions in front of me but I guess I'm not sure how to utilize them properly:

- actionRegions
- multiple forms

The `pageBlockButtons` wants to be the direct child of the `pageBlock`. Therefore I cannot wrap it inside a form. Also if I wrap the buttons inside `actionRegions` that will bypass validation.

Comment: do you use Contact.Account.Name as example contact field, or you want to update account itself?

Comment: @IlyaLepesh I am updating the Account itself.

Comment: Could you please describe what kind of validation do you need? Only page validation, that field was provided? Or you talking about validation rules, each for object?

Comment: @IlyaLepesh page validation

Answer (score 1):

I believe wrapping the field-button pairs in `actionRegions` does the job! That way each button validates its counterpart field. Finally the main page-level button can be left alone to operate normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be no problem when you use validation code in controller. Both Command button call different methods. In `updateContact()` method, write validation of contact and in method `updateAccount()` write validation of account.

Hope it may helps you.